# Question on the verification of two limits (with the definition)

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, solution-verification, definition

I need to understand those things better. Say I have to check for the correctness, or not, of the limit $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{n+1} = 1$$
Now I know the limit is false, but I want to verify with the definition, closing with a contradiction or a violation of the same.

So I know that in this case $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists M_{\epsilon} > 0$ such that when $n > M$ we have $| f(n) - \ell | < \epsilon$.

Then here
$$\Big| \frac{1}{n+1} - 1\Big| < \epsilon \implies \Big| \frac{-n}{n+1}\Big| < \epsilon $$

Hence we can solve getting $n > \frac{-\epsilon}{\epsilon -1}$.

Then it suffices to take $M_{\epsilon} = \frac{-\epsilon}{\epsilon -1}$

- Can we say the limit is false because this does violate the statement? I mean the part $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists M > 0$. This is false if we choose $\epsilon = 1$ or $\epsilon = 1.01$.
- In regart to my previous point: is it legit to choose such a "large" $\epsilon$? I mean I know the definition reads $\forall \epsilon > 0$, but I sometimes (wrongly) think that we "need" always something like $\epsilon \to 0$, I mean positive but very little.

I wanted to ask another question here, but I'll ask it in a different topic.

Thank you for the moment.

Comment: **Hint** $$\left|\frac{1}{n+1}-1\right|=\left|\frac{n}{n+1}\right|\geq \frac{1}{2}$$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: @Surb Tell me if I get it right: thanks to your hing, I shall deduce that since that quantity is $\geq 1/2$, and since we want it also $< \epsilon$, we come tothe conclusion that it's not true that it holds $\forall \epsilon > 0$, right? 

Or is it something else which I cannot get...

Comment: Not clear what you mean. However, this mean that $\lim_{n\to \infty }\left|\frac{1}{n+1}-1\right|\geq \frac{1}{2}$, and thus $\frac{1}{n+1}$ doesn't converges to $1$. A way to use $\varepsilon $ proof, take $\varepsilon =\frac{1}{2}$, then, for all $n\in \mathbb N$,  taking $N_n=n$ gives $\left|1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right|\geq \varepsilon $.

Comment: @Surb Thank you again, but this doesn't point out where I'm wrong in my question. Can't I just choose $\epsilon = 1.01$, to say, just to verify that the result doesn't hold for every $\epsilon$?

Comment: Having some $\varepsilon >0$ s.t. $|1/(n+1)-1|<\varepsilon $ is not enough ! What you need is to have is that **for all** $\varepsilon >0$ there is $N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. for all $n\geq N$, $|1/(n+1)-1|<\varepsilon $ .

Comment: They error you made is that you assumed the conclusion. You're trying to prove that $|\frac1{n+1} - 1| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$. You can't say that it is that way and proceed to calculate from there. In general you should assume $\epsilon$ is small, almost infinitesimal. That's the case which gives you the most insight into the limit.

Comment: @Numb3rs I think that what Surb told you in the first answer is -- for epsilon = 0.5, you can never find such M. So the statement "for every epsilon there exists M" is not true. It's quite simple, don't overcomplicate it.

Comment: @CyclotomicField So you mean that the way to proceed in those kind of exercises is not to start from the inequality? I have been taught wrong? I thought one had to start from the inequality, then derive the $M_{\epsilon}$ term and find, if possible just a counterexample for which the inequality fails, in this case for $\epsilon = 1.01$. I understood Surb explanation, but it looks like very far from what I learnt...

Comment: @Surb Perhaps I wasn't clear. The string I focused on was $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$. This one. I thought that by choosing/noticing that $\epsilon = 1.01$, that statement would be false. Indeed $M = \frac{-\epsilon}{\epsilon -1}$ implies $M = \frac{-1.01}{0.01} = -101$, which is NOT $M > 0$. 
I don't get what's wrong with my method...

Comment: @PeterFranek Thank you, but in what what is that different from what I wrote? I just found one $\epsilon$, that is $1.01$ for which it does not exist $M > 0$ (since $M$ would be negative). Why is Surb method better or right, wrt mine? It's not just "exists $M$". It's "exists $M > 0$".

Comment: @Numb3rs it's often useful to start by assuming the result you want to prove and then try to work backwards however to be successful you'll have to find a valid solution. Here you're trying to choose an $n$ that works but you've assumed $|\frac{-n}{n+1}|<\epsilon$ when you need to be choosing an $n$ that makes this true. As you noted the choice of $M_\epsilon$ you've come up with doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @Numb3rs No, epsilon = 1.01 does not work. For this epsilon, there actually exist M -- for instance M = 100 -- such that for each n > M, you actually have $| n/(n+1)| < 1.01$. But for epsilon = 0.5 , you can not find such M.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question, but actually you can use the negative proposition for help.

The definition of limit of a sequence is that
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists N \in \mathbb N \forall n > N(|a_n - a| < \varepsilon).$$
Therefore the negative proposition of it should be
$$\exists \varepsilon > 0 \forall N \in \mathbb N \exists n > N(|a_n - a| \geq \varepsilon).$$
What you need to prove is that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac 1 {n + 1} \neq 1.$$
So the goal is to find such an $\varepsilon$. Then here we have
$$|\frac 1 {n + 1} - 1| = |\frac n {n+1}| \geq \varepsilon,$$
if we take an arbitrary $\varepsilon$, like $\varepsilon = 1 / 2$ just as @Surb said, then that will be $n \geq 1$, so we say that we have found an $\varepsilon  = 1 / 2$ that for all $N \in \mathbb N$, we can choose $n = \max\{1, N + 1\} > N$ s.t. $\left|\dfrac 1 {n + 1} - 1\right| \geq \varepsilon = \dfrac 1 2$, which proves what you want.

> Notice that not all $\varepsilon > 0$ has a corresponding $n$ that suffices the proposition with it. e.g., let $\varepsilon = 2$. Then we have $n \leq -2$, which is impossible for a sequence. This is obvious since the negative proposition only require us to pick a specific $\varepsilon$ but not all.

In your question you say that you are not sure whether choosing a relatively big number is legit, but actually you can verify that if one $\varepsilon$ don not satisfy the positive proposition, all $\varepsilon$ smaller than it do not so according to the negetive proposition.

You can imagine an interval of $(1 - \varepsilon, 1 + \varepsilon)$ and let $\varepsilon$ change from a big number to small one. When it is big enough, it can contain all infinite terms of $a_n$. But at some points it fails, like the example of $1/2$. So only finite terms will fall into the interval, which is contradictory to the definition, which says all $x_n (n > N)$ fall into a neighbourhood of $a$, indicating that there are infinite terms in it.